# Is there an array method for testing multiple equality values?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to know where array a is equal to *any* of the values in array b.

For example,

```
a = np.random.randint(0,16, size=(3,4))
b = np.array([2,3,9])

# like this, but for any size b:
locations = np.nonzero((a==b[0]) | (a==b[1]) | (a==b[3]))
```

The reason is so I can change the values in a from (any of b) to another value:

```
a[locations] = 99
```

Or-ing the equality checks is not a great solution, because I would like to do this without knowing the size of b ahead of time. Is there an array solution?

[edit]
There are now 2 good answers to this question, one using broadcasting with extra dimensions, and another using `np.in1d`. Both work for the specific case in this question. I ended up using `np.isin` instead, since it seems like it is more agnostic to the shapes of both `a` and `b`.
I accepted the answer that taught me about `in1d` since that led me to my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.in1d` then `reshape` back to `a`'s shape so you can set the values in `a` to your special flag.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(410012)

a = np.random.randint(0, 16, size=(3, 4))
#array([[ 8,  5,  5, 15],
#       [ 3, 13,  8, 10],
#       [ 3, 11,  0, 10]])

b = np.array([[2,3,9], [4,5,6]])
```

---

```
a[np.in1d(a, b).reshape(a.shape)] = 999
#array([[  8, 999, 999,  15],
#       [999,  13,   8,  10],
#       [999,  11,   0,  10]])
```

Comment: I didn't know about `in1d`, but it led me to `isin`, which I like even better. Thanks for teaching me a new thing about numpy.

Answer (score 1):

> Or-ing the equality checks is not a great solution, **because I would like to do this without knowing the size of b ahead of time**.

#### EDIT:

Vectorized equivalent to the code you have written above -

```
a = np.random.randint(0,16, size=(3,4))
b = np.array([2,3,9])

locations = np.nonzero((a==b[0]) | (a==b[1]) | (a==b[2]))

locations2 = np.nonzero((a[None,:,:]==b[:,None,None]).any(0))

np.allclose(locations, locations2)
```

```
True
```

This shows that your output is exactly the same as this output, without the need of explicitly mentioning `b[0], b[1]...` or using a for loop.

---

#### Explanation -

1. Broadcasting an operation can help you in this case. What you are trying to do is to compare each of the `(3,4)` matrix elements to each value in `b` which is `(3,)`. This means that the resultant boolean matrix that you want is going to be three, (3,4) matrices, or `(3,3,4)`
2. Once you have done that, you want to take an `ANY` or `OR` between the three (3,4) matrices element-wise. That would reduce the `(3,3,4)` to a `(3,4)`
3. Finally you want to use `np.nonzero` to identify the locations where values are equal to `TRUE`

The above 3 steps can be done as follows -

- Broadcasting comparison operation:

```
a[None,:,:]==b[:,None,None]] #(1,3,4) == (3,1,1) -> (3,3,4)
```

- Reduction using OR logic:

```
(a[None,:,:]==b[:,None,None]).any(0)  #(3,3,4) -> (3,4)
```

- Get non-zero locations:

```
np.nonzero((a[None,:,:]==b[:,None,None]).any(0))
```

Comment: This does not tell me where these items appear in a.

Comment: You can completely vectorize the above operation. I am adding an update to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.isin` works on multi-dimensional `a` and `b`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0, 16, size=(3, 4)); a
Out[2]:
array([[12,  2, 15, 11],
       [12, 15,  5, 10],
       [ 4,  2, 14,  7]])

In [3]: b = [2, 4, 5, 12]

In [4]: c = [[2, 4], [5, 12]]

In [5]: np.isin(a, b).astype(int)
Out[5]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])

In [6]: np.isin(a, c).astype(int)
Out[6]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])

In [7]: a[np.isin(a, b)] = 99; a
Out[7]:
array([[99, 99, 15, 11],
       [99, 15, 99, 10],
       [99, 99, 14,  7]])
```